# can we use "is" after using "and"?

Tags: sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

> this stream of media messages in which violence `and` physicals
> aggression `is` portrayed as a good thing gradually alters our belief
> that violence is bad.

after using `and`, can we use `"is"`? I thought I have to use `are` after using `and`.

Comment: **Violence** and **physical aggression** are two things, so it should be **are**. I suppose the writer is mentally lumping them together as part of the same phenomenon.

Comment: @KateBunting - "Shocking sex and violence is part of opera says defiant Royal Opera House boss"

Comment: If "violence and physical aggression" are considered as a single phenomenon/concept, then it's fine.   Other similar examples "pain and suffering is ..." , "science and technology is ...", "law and order is ..."

Comment: @BillyKerr - you will always be safer to pick the plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Violence and physical aggression are two things, so it should be "are". I suppose the writer is mentally lumping them together as part of the same phenomenon. - @KateBunting

Based on the subject verb agreement, a plural subject - "violence and physical aggression" - takes a plural verb - "are".

Comment: Interestingly, some fixed phrases made up of noun - and - noun can be treated as singular or plural e.g. "All this fun and games is not looked upon with disapproval", vs. " fun and games commence" - examples given in Longman's Dictionary.

Comment: @MicaelHarvey, I would say it doesn't even have to be a fixed noun phrase. If two things can be viewed as a single concept, then it is possible to use the singular verb agreement. It's generally optional though, not something set in stone.